# increase height of div for each added element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am outputting comments from my database using a while loop now I would like for each added comment that the height of a certain div increases how should I do this? I was thinking about making a for loop that counts the number of comments outputted with the while loop and then increase the css height for each counted div in the for loop. But I don't really know how to increment the height at the end.

```js
//While loop which outputs the comments
<div class="commentwrapper">
while($rowcomments = mysqli_fetch_array($resultgetcomments)){
echo "<div class='commentdiv'>
 <p class='commentuser'> Posted by: '".$rowcomments['CommentUsername']."' on: '".$rowcomments['CommentDate']."'</p> '".$rowcomments['CommentTxt']."'</div>
```

```js
for(var i = 0; i < rowcomments.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('#commentwrapper');
        commentwrapper.style.height = /* here I would like to increase the height per 250px for each outputted comment*/;

}
```

Comment: typo, commentswrapper or commentwrapper?

Comment: yeah noticed it was only for example sake that I used those names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS to the rescue. No JS necessary.

```
.commentwrapper {
    display: table; /* Make the container element behave like a table */
}

.commentdiv {
    display: table-cell; /* Make elements inside the container behave like table cells */
}
```

Comment: this one is coming pretty close ! but to get full solution I would need to use the loop since I want to trick the browser into thinking this is just prolonged body... for some reason the outputted elements with the while don't get recognised as body so my background just stops at the comments

Comment: Ok after fiddling a bit with my stylesheet this is by far the easiest way to go learned something now about CSS today thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method inside the for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowcomments.length; i++){
    $('#commentwrapper').animate({'height': '+=250px'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowcomments.length; i++){
var commentwrapper =  document.getElementById("#commentwrapper");
if(height===null){
var height = document.getElementById("#commentwrapper").style.height;
}
else{
height=height + 250;
}
    commentwrapper.style.height = height;
}
```

Comment: I think this would work but I need to be able to define row comments from the while loop to the js script any thoughts?

Comment: I update the code here with in for loop it will be check if null define it else increase it 250